Use tf.autodiff.ForwardAccumulator inside a function decorated with tf.function (RNN)
In Tensorflow, I need to evaluate the Jacobian-vector product using the function tf.autodiff.ForwardAccumulator(). Everything works fine unless I decorate the function with @tf.function. In that case I get this error:
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling GRU.call().

`dtype` <dtype: 'variant'> is not compatible with 1 of dtype int64.

Arguments received by GRU.call():
  • sequences=tf.Tensor(shape=(128, 64, 1), dtype=float64)
  • initial_state=None
  • mask=None
  • training=False

I tried swapping the GRU layers with Dense layers, and it works fine with and without the decorator. I guess that the problem has something to do with the transformation of the model in a graph.
Here is a code to reproduce the error on Tensorflow v2.16.1:
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.normal([128, 64, 1], dtype=tf.float64)
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True, activation=tf.nn.relu, dtype=tf.float64, use_cudnn=False)
layer2 = tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True, activation=tf.nn.relu, dtype=tf.float64, use_cudnn=False)
layer3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu, dtype=tf.float64)

tangent = tf.ones((128, 64, 1), dtype=tf.float64)

@tf.function
def jac_vec_prod(inp, tangent):
    with tf.autodiff.ForwardAccumulator(primals=inp, tangents=tangent) as acc:
        feature = layer1(inp)
        feature = layer2(feature)
        out = layer3(feature)    
    jvp = acc.jvp(out)
    return jvp

jvp = jac_vec_prod(inp=x, tangent=tangent)

